# How to make rotating shape look thick?

Tags: html, css

I have created this locker opening type of effect, but without a thick door, it is not looking very good. How can I add some thickness to the door so that it looks like a locker door?
Anything else i can do to make it look more realistic?

Only CSS solution please, no JavaScript.

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
 position: relative;
}
#maincircle {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 200px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 perspective: 600px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#door, #back {
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: grey;
 top: 1px;
 left: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 99%;
 height: 99%;
 transition: transform 2s 0.5s;
 transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
#door {
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#locker {
 position: absolute;
 top: 25px;
 left: 25px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background-image: url(https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/806e9122/dms3rep/multi/tablet/CombinationLock-1000x1000.png);
 background-size: 150px 150px;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}
#maincircle:hover #door #locker {
    transform: rotate(90deg); 
}
#maincircle:hover #door, #maincircle:hover #back {
 transform: rotateY(-110deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="container">
      <div id="maincircle">
       <div id="back"></div>
       <div id="door"><div id="locker"></div></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after` to give the door some thickness. I made a rough example for you but please modify (change colors, add prefixes to the css etc) it to your needs.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.maincircle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  perspective: 600px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d; 
}
.door {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  transition: .5s linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.door:before {
  background-color: gray;
  background-image: linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.25), hsla(0,0%,0%,.25));
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: '';
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateZ(-5px);
}

.door:after {
  background-color: gray;
  background-image: linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.25), hsla(0,0%,0%,.25));
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 5px;
  z-index: -10;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.maincircle:hover .door {
  transition: transform 2s 0.5s;
  transform: rotateY(-110deg);
}

.maincircle:hover .locker {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.locker {
   background-image: url("https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/806e9122/dms3rep/multi/tablet/CombinationLock-1000x1000.png"); 
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="maincircle">
      <div class="door">
        <div class="locker"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```